# Clone/Duplicate EC2 Windows Instance

Tags: active-directory, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ami, clone

I have a **Windows Server 2008 EC2 instance** hosting SQL Server 2008 named DB-01. I'm looking to **clone this DB-01 instance** so my team can work on the cloned DB-01 (DB-01-CLN) and existing DB-01 instances side by side. I **restored an AMI** of DB-01 and **assigned a different IP**.

The issue im running into now is that the existing DB-01 server is **joined to a domain**. When I logged into the cloned instance and updated the **host name** it changed the name of the existing **DB-01 computer object in active directory**. This change prevented me from logging into the existing the DB-01 server with my AD credentials.

I need a way to **clone this windows 2008 instance that is AD joined** so I can run the existing server and cloned server side by side. Is there something I can do that'll create the cloned instance as a *separate instance altogether*? By that I mean c**reate its own AD computer object so it doesn't interfere with the existing server**?

Thanks,

Comment: Upgraded the EC2ConfigService to latest, edited the sysprep2008.xml and added a local admin account/password - opened the EC2ConfigService - unchecked enable hibernation option, keep existing admin password, click Shutdown with sysprep. In aws console I used instance settings > get instance screenshot option to check on boot up process of VM. Once done I RDP'd with admin account entered in sysprep2008.xml file, I was able to use the key pair I generated when VM first created. Forced to enter new host name on logging in then joined to domain and good to go. Both instances are running now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible; but you will have to shutdown and sysprep the source machine (or the clone, when logged on locally).

Comment: Correct, when I mentioned above the step "Shutdown with sysprep" that was performed on the cloned instance. The feature/option is included in EC2ConfigService. I did not have to sysprep the original instance, just the clone. Once the clone was sysrepped and rebooted I was able to join both instances back to the domain (clone had new host name assigned) without issue.